# Use SELECT2 plugin into Laravel Livewire with remote searchable feature

Tags: laravel, jquery-select2, laravel-livewire

I use SELECT2 ( v4.0.13 ) into Laravel Livewire ( v2.4.4 ).

And I want to use SELECT2 to fetch remote data with Laravel Livewire by typing some perms just like using the build-in ajax feature. But I can not use `wire:model` to bind any Livewire properties to the SELECT2 search input field.

Any help is appreciated. Or are there any other alternative packages I can use to instead SELECT2.
Thanks.